# Datagrid failing to populate with Dataset - Input string not in correct format

Tags: c#, datagrid, dataset, sqldataadapter

I have a datagrid view in which I set value like this

```
string query = "select CustomerId,CustomerName from tbl_Customer where flag=0";
SqlDataAdapter daCustomer = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);

daCustomer.Fill(ds, "Customer");

cmbCustomerName.DisplayMember = "CustomerName";
cmbCustomerName.ValueMember = "CustomerId";
cmbCustomerName.DataSource = ds.Tables["Customer"];
cmbCustomerName.ResetText();
```

but it gives me this error after this line

```
 cmbCustomerName.DataSource = ds.Tables["Customer"];
```

when I set datasource. Please help me fix this.

Comment: Which line is the error on? Could be your connection string as well which you've not shown.

Comment: is ur DataSet getting filled? what table name it is showing. Like @Dave said on which line error is encountered

Comment: After showing the above error the form gets displayed and the combpbox gets filled with the result of query

Comment: have you tried this  cmbCustomerName.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

Comment: @Usman, tried but in vain.. :( :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
daCustomer.Fill(dt);
cmbCustomerName.DataSource = dt;
```